# Unable to use Google SVN with Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-indigo

I'm facing a problem in configuring Google SVN with Eclipse Indigo. It is not accepting the URL of the repository. Anybody please tell which URL is to be given?

Comment: Could you provide more of a description of what is going wrong? Maybe an error message you're receiving, or steps you've taken to reproduce the problem?

Comment: How did you try? Here is a correct example: http://dpkt.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ where dpkt is a projectname.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using url in form of https instead of http.